# nginx fbclid remove from url

Tags: facebook, nginx, vaadin8, hashbang

I have following nginx rewrite. But from simple html link work it very well and from facebook not. First time go to correct url and shortly after few seconds to home url.

```
if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)fbclid=(.*)$") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

url structure is following:

```
https://tld.com?fbclid=IwAR0B_MwRdL9H6OXoAINh1mOFL81J-MV4jOSg2qjaCPs7l4fawFIwYiLv7r4#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/авто-мото/суудлын/богино/449682/fit-зарна
```

[example link](https://negdoor.mn?fbclid=IwAR0B_MwRdL9H6OXoAINh1mOFL81J-MV4jOSg2qjaCPs7l4fawFIwYiLv7r4#!%D1%82%D3%A9%D0%BC%D3%A9%D1%80-%D1%85%D2%AF%D0%BB%D1%8D%D0%B3/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BD/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE/449682/fit-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0)

question: Why this link not working from facebook?

Comment: for test copy example url and share in facebook and click. You will redirected to home page.

Comment: fbclid patameter removed from vaadin UI and fixed.